# How to use tabs.executeScript with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

In one of my components, when the component is loaded, I want my extension to inject a script into the current tab that the extension is run on. The script essentially gets the source code and save it as a string.

So, in my `componentWillMount` I tried to inject the script in the following way...

```
componentWillMount() {

    var result = '';
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: './js/scripts/getPageSource.js'
     }, function() {
        // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            result = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;

        }
    });
}
```

The path of my script, `./js/scripts/getPageSource.js` is relative to my `index.html` file that is being used by my react app.

I get the error file is not found, so I changed the path relative to the component, but I still go file not found.

I'm thinking maybe this is not the right way to inject a script into an open tab with react, is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Here is my `manifest.json` file...

```
{
  "name": "Get pages source",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get pages source from a popup",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "src/index.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

My path `./js/scripts/getPageSource.js` is located inside my `src` folder being referenced above

Comment: @Makyen If you need me to add the manifest file and the script being called, I can do so. But my main issue is I am trying to inject a script and it is not being called at all. As far as I can tell, you don't really need to know what the script does do you?

Comment: @Makyen ok I added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a path that is relative to your *manfest.json* file.

[MDN states:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript#Parameters)

> In Firefox, relative URLs are resolved relative to the current page URL. In Chrome, these URLs are **resolved relative to the add-on's base URL**.

From your *manifest.json*, it looks like your `file` should be:

```
file: 'src/js/scripts/getPageSource.js'
```

Comment: can I inject react js components into a website using this method?