# How to open a Firefox WebExtension options page as a tab, separate from about:addons

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So, I've looked through the WebExtensions API, but I haven't been able to figure out how to open an HTML page separate from `about:addons` for options. In the Add-on SDK you could have `resource://ext-id-/path/to/file.html`. I've tried making a directory web accessible and putting an HTML file in there, but that didn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can open the options HTML file in it's own tab with WebExtensions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create

Comment: That doesn't talk about opening a page from the extension in the tab. The options.html page inside the extension is what I want to open in a tab.

Comment: "Relative URLs will be relative to the current page within the extension."

Comment: Thanks for that, missed that one little line. :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Opening a tab

**Options page *always* in a tab:**
If you want your options page to *always* open in a tab, you can add the property `open_in_tab` with a value of `true` to the `options_ui` key in your *manifest.json*:

```
"options_ui" : {
  "page": "options.html",
  "open_in_tab":true
}
```

This will result in your options page always opening in a tab. Both clicking on your extension's "Options" from within `about:addons` and using [`runtime.openOptionsPage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage) will result in your options page opening in a tab.

Thanks to [BigBlutHat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507169/bigbluehat) for reminding me of this option.

**In a tab when normally your options page is within `about:addons`:**
You can open a new tab with whatever URL from within your extension you desire, including your options page, using [`tabs.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create) and [`runtime.getURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getURL).  Specifically for an `options.html` file located in the same directory as your *manifest.json*, the following works:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL('/options.html')
});
```

**Does not need to be web accessible and loading JavaScript:**
You do not need the files to be declared as web accessible. The page runs in the background context so JavaScript is loaded by directly including the files in the `src` of a `<script>` tag (e.g. `<script src="/options.js">`). This is the same as you would do for a popup.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39236352/3773011) has an extension that uses the same HTML and JavaScript as both a popup and an options page. It does not, however, actually show opening that page as a tab, but it could be done with the above code.

**Resolving Relative URLs:**
Both [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create#Parameters) state:

> Relative URLs will be relative to the current page within the extension.

Note: For all the different `chrome.*` API calls, Chrome and Firefox do not always resolve relative URLs in the same way.  For example, it is different in each browser for [`chrome.executeScript()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40474627/3773011).

Comment: Quick question. How can I get a content script to run on it. Specifying moz-extension://... in the matches array causes the extension to be invalid. Trying to set the scripts to be web-accessible and calling it inside of <script> tags also doesn't work.

Comment: @KnightYoshi, The page is not loaded in the content context. It is in the background page context. Thus, scripts are included directly as paths (not `moz-extension://`, but just `/options.js`) similar to what you would do with a popup page. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39236352/3773011) includes a page that is used as both an options page and a popup.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm quite new to the WebExtensions API, it's quite different than the SDK version.

Comment: @KnightYoshi, I'm glad I am able to help.  Something I noticed I did not address from your question: You do not need to declare the resources as web accessible. I have added the info from my comments to the Answer.

Comment: There's also the `openOptionsPage()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage It is somewhat less widely supported (at present), but nice and clear about what it does.

Comment: @BigBlueHat, Yes, that is the normal method of opening an options page. However, the question was specifically about how to open an options page in a tab, "separate from `about:addons`". `openOptionsPage()` opens the options page within `about:options`. Thus, it was specifically not what the OP was looking for as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Makyen I've used the `openOptionsPage()` method with a brower_action click event setup in a background script and it opens in a new tab completely outside of the `about:options` space--which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: @BigBlueHat, Interesting. I have used `openOptionsPage()` before, and just tested it again prior to posting my earlier comment. In all my use/testing, while it does open a new tab, that tab is to the extension's options page within `about:addons` (multiple versions of Firefox tested, just now). Please describe in more detail exactly what you did to get it to open outside of `about:addons`.

Comment: It uses the `open_in_tab` options inside the `options` object in the manifest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/options_ui#Syntax

Comment: @BigBlueHat, Strange, I thought I had tested that previously (some time ago, don't remember which version) and not had it work.  Thanks for pointing out that it is working.

Comment: @BigBlueHat, I updated the Answer with that information.  Thanks again for reminding me about it.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out in the updated answer @Makyen! :) Glad it was helpful info.