# Open the about:addons page with my plugin's options page on screen

Tags: javascript, firefox, hyperlink, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

In Firefox, is there a way to open the add-on's own options page within `about:addons` through a button in the add-on? (Not just the *options.html* page by itself, but within the `about:addons` page, the same one that you can get to when pressing "more" beside the description of the add-on).

I got this:

```js
function OpenOptionsMenu() {
  browser.tabs.create({
  url: "???"
});
```

But, I have no idea what to put as the URL.

I found this: `browser.runtime.getURL('/options.html')`, but that will only get the options page by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [command to do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage) is:

```js
chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
```

or

```js
browser.runtime.openOptionsPage();
```

This will open the options page displayed as it would normally be if the user clicked on the <kbd>Options</kbd> button from `about:addons`. If it is supposed to be displayed within `about:addons` (i.e. `open_in_tab` not specified in [`options_ui`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/options_ui)) then it will be displayed in `about:addons`.

If you did specify `open_in_tab` in the `options_ui` key within your *manifest.json*, then it will be opened in a separate tab. With `open_in_tab` specified, there no way to open it within `about:addons`. If `open_in_tab` is not specified you can [open it in a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519074/how-to-open-a-firefox-webextension-options-page-as-a-tab-separate-from-aboutad/40519638#40519638), or window, should you choose to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function specifically for this:

```
browser.runtime.openOptionsPage()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage

However, opening the options page in a separate tab is a perfectly valid UI choice.

Comment: You nija'ed me by a few seconds. If you want to put the information about `open_in_tab` into your answer, I'll delete mine.